# Looking for accoustic percussion sound pack.Can be both free & paid

Tags: samples

I'm looking for a sample pack (or vst plugin, but I think there are none) with accoustic percussion. Right now I'm using sibelius to write the sheetmusic directly. But I would like to switch to FL Studio (which I already own) to compose in therte and then export midi over to sibelius. (I've heard that is a very common pattern, makes sense I guess)

So I'd like the pack to contain both one shot and drum rolls. the instruments I'd like to have:

- Snaredrum
- Fielddrum / tenor drum
- bongos
- congas
- drumset
- tom-toms (at least 4)
- cymbals
- small percussive instruments (not really nesseccary but nice to have)
  like
- cowbell
- woodblock
- finger cymbals

I'm really loving the sibelius sounds percussion sounds so anything like that would be awsome.

Any pointers to sample packs are very much appreciated! (free as well as paid)

Comment: Requests for resources like this are off topic on this side. But a quick google for „acoustic drum sample library“ will point you to a ton of different libraries.